# Object does not support this property or method in IE

Tags: jquery, object, internet-explorer-8

Once again I need help

The following code works fine in all browsers except IE, IE8 that is. The problem area is:

```
$(function () {
    $('area').live('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
        mapObject.qmap($(this), event);
    });
});
});
```

The complete code is:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var mapObject = {
         qmap: function (area, event) {
             var ida = area.attr('name');
             if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
                 $('.' + ida).show();
                 $('#' + ida).siblings().each(function () {
                     if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                         $(this).hide();
                     }
                 });
                 $('#' + ida).show();
             }
             else {
                 $('.' + ida).hide();
                 $('#' + ida).hide();
                 $('#map-0').hide();
             }
         }
     };
     $(function () {
         $('area').live('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
             mapObject.qmap($(this), event);
         });
     });
 });
```

I tried to work it out from the other similar post with no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: not sure that this is a fix, but .live is deprecated in current versions of jquery.  use .on() instead

Comment: $('area').live('mouseover mouseout', function (event) { Sorry not sure how you mean to use just .on()?

Comment: @Laurence L: shouldn't it be `$('#area')` instead?

Comment: @Laurence L: see my update for how to use .on()

Comment: Hi J. Bruni - No the 'area' is referencing the map coords area. Sample here http://ccq-staging.brightlabs.com.au/page/information_resources/vcrcc-qld-map/

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple version like this:

```
$(function() {
    function mapObject(e) {
        var area = $(this);
        var ida = area.attr('name');
        if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
            $('.' + ida).show();
            $('#' + ida).siblings().each(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
            $('#' + ida).show();
        } else {
            $('.' + ida).hide();
            $('#' + ida).hide();
            $('#map-0').hide();
        }
    }
    $(document).on('mouseover mouseout', 'area', mapObject);
});
```

Comment: .on works but is not the problem. I tried the global mapObject but it made no difference, Sample of what I am trying to do here http://ccq-staging.brightlabs.com.au/page/information_resources/vcrcc-qld-map/

Comment: @Laurence L: When you declare the global mapObject, you **can't** use `var` when referencing it inside the function! Anyway, I have completely changed my answer...

Comment: Got it working. The issue was a conflict with another script. Thanks for the help and I'll use .on() in place of .live from now on